# mysql Innodb engine disappear

Tags: mysql, innodb

I had to change the tmpdir directory from /tmp to /db/tmp/ folder due to the fact I didn't have enough space. When I changed my path and I ran SHOW ENGINES; I got below result;

1. ARCHIVE
2. MRG_MYISAM
3. CSV
4. MYISAM
5. MEMORY

But, when I changed the directory back to /tmp my Innodb engine came back. SHOW ENGINES;

1. ARCHIVE
2. MRG_MYISAM
3. CSV
4. MYISAM
5. MEMORY
6. InnoDB

Does anyone know why MySQL is acting strange like that? This is a show stopper for me and causing my production server to crash.

Comment: What is in that tmp folder? Anything with .001 .002 .003, etc? --Nevermind, I read tables, you were asking about engines.

Comment: there is nothing there

Comment: can you check mysqld.log and see if any problems logged into log file?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir=/db/tmp
```

then `service mysql restart` (For [**tmpdir**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir), restart is required)

Also, run this in Linux just in case:

```
$ chown mysql:mysql /db/tmp
$ chmod 777 /db/tmp
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Done that but still same issue!